# which one is best web service like Asynk task and volley web service in android

Tags: json, rest, android-asynctask, android-volley, android-webservice

what is the def. between this web service like **Volley** and **Asynk task** web service in android and which one best.

*i am using restfull web service with using Asynk task but i dint now what is the deference between this two.*

Comment: some one please explain briefly thank you

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-get-json-from-server/ i fund the tutorial for volley web service

Answer (score 0):

By Using **AsyncTask WeCan Send** Data As well as **Files** too, But by using **Volley**  You can Send and Receive **String Response**(i.e Text Formatted JsonArray,JsonObject,String.....etc) only.......

Comment: its fine but i want to more information thank you..(*^_^*)

Comment: A major advantage of Android Volley over AsyncTask is that you can do multiple requests simultaneously without the overhead of thread management. Also I believe retry mechanism is a great feature of volley which gives it an edge over AsynTask. Another advantage of volley over AsyncTask is that it provides you with multiple request types, through which complex requests can be made easily. On the other hand while using AsyncTasks one would have to create this type of request manually. See the Image in this Link, http://instructure.github.io/blog/2013/12/09/volley-vs-retrofit/